# How to add two square buttons on title bar in Codename One?

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to make the title bar with two square buttons on left(for side menu) and right side of screen. I haven't problem with left button, but I can't make right button's shape similar to left button. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO and [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Sidemenu is builtin to CodenameOne and much easier with the `Toolbar` class see:

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_toolbar

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/cats-in-toolbars.html

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toolbar.html